# CS: GO Deathmatch loadout bug

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When playing vanilla Death match in CS:GO, I notice that on occasion I get a random gun which is not available for my team. I play with random weapons **Off** and I use buy binds to switch guns (also using the "G" button to occasionally get the bonus weapon). Is there any explanation/ solution to how to stop this from occurring?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of this? Cause this sounds like a bunch of nonsense to be honest.

Comment: It rarely occurs,but I will once I can. @Sickest